# Shell script cd command in Jenkins pipeline is giving error "no such file or directory"

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline script for file transfer job in which I am trying to read a CSV file (FileTransferCSV.csv) from server and perform the actions accordingly. Under the script block after reading the CSV file, "scp" command to copy a file from Jenkins Server to Actual testing transfer is working fine but "cd" to the Target Server is giving error

> no such file or directory

Below is the part of the Jenkins pipeline script:

```
stage('Parsing the CSV and Transferring Files')
{
     steps {
        script {
            readFile("${WORKSPACE}/archives/TEST/FileTransferCSV.csv").split('\n').each { line  ->
                if (!line.contains("Action,Source Path,File Name,Destination Path"))
                {
                    def fields = line.split(',')
                    for(String item: fields) {
                        println item
                    }

                    if (fields[0].equals("UPDATE") || fields[0].equals("INSERT"))
                    {
                        if (fields[1] == null || fields[1].isEmpty())
                        {
                            sh (script :  "scp -r ${WORKSPACE}/archives/TEST/${fields[2]} asapuser@${ASAP_IP}:${SERVER_PATH}/${fields[3]} " , returnStdout: true).trim();
                            echo "------------Files copied to Target server--------------"
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sh (script : "scp -r ${WORKSPACE}/archives/TEST/${fields[1]}/${fields[2]} asapuser@${ASAP_IP}:${SERVER_PATH}/${fields[3]} " , returnStdout: true).trim();
                            echo "------------Files copied to Target server--------------"
                        }
                    }

                    if (fields[0] == "DELETE")
                    {
                        sh (script : "#!/bin/bash",returnStdout: true).trim();
                        sh (script : "cd asapuser@${ASAP_IP}:${SERVER_PATH}/ZDP/${fields[3]}",returnStdout: true).trim();
                        sh (script : "rm -r asapuser@${ASAP_IP}:${fields[2]}",returnStdout: true).trim();
                        echo "------------Files deleted from Target server--------------"
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For "DELETE" Action, the destination path and file name are populating correctly but error is coming "no such file or directory". I have checked the file location from terminal with the same command and it's working.

Below is the output of the pipeline:

```
[Pipeline] { (Parsing the CSV and Transferring Files)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] readFile
[Pipeline] echo
23:16:46  UPDATE
[Pipeline] echo
23:16:46  ONENDS
[Pipeline] echo
23:16:46  MODIFY_HLR_ADD_PRIMARY.xml
[Pipeline] echo
23:16:47  property_files/ONENDS
[Pipeline] sh
23:16:47  + scp -r /home/tomcat/.jenkins/workspace/ASAP_PROPERTY_FILES_DEPLOY_PIPELINE/archives/TEST/ONENDS/MODIFY_HLR_ADD_PRIMARY.xml asapuser@10.162.53.18:/opt/asap/asap/property_files/ONENDS
[Pipeline] echo
23:16:59  ------------Files copied to Target server--------------
[Pipeline] echo
23:17:11  INSERT
[Pipeline] echo
23:17:11  
[Pipeline] echo
23:17:12  NEW
[Pipeline] echo
23:17:12  property_files
[Pipeline] sh
23:17:12  + scp -r /home/tomcat/.jenkins/workspace/ASAP_PROPERTY_FILES_DEPLOY_PIPELINE/archives/TEST/NEW asapuser@10.162.53.18:/opt/asap/asap/property_files
[Pipeline] echo
23:17:24  ------------Files copied to Target server--------------
[Pipeline] echo
23:17:49  DELETE
[Pipeline] echo
23:17:49  
[Pipeline] echo
23:17:49  DUMMY
[Pipeline] echo
23:17:49  NEW_DUMMY
[Pipeline] sh
23:08:43  + cd asapuser@10.162.53.18:/opt/asap/asap/ZDP/NEW_DUMMY
23:08:43  /home/tomcat/.jenkins/workspace/ASAP_PROPERTY_FILES_DEPLOY_PIPELINE@tmp/durable-568d025c/script.sh: line 1: cd: asapuser@10.162.53.18:/opt/asap/asap/ZDP/NEW_DUMMY: No such file or directory
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
```

Below is the CSV file:

```
Action,Source Path,File Name,Destination Path
UPDATE,ONENDS,MODIFY_HLR_ADD_PRIMARY.xml,property_files/ONENDS
INSERT,,NEW,property_files
DELETE,,DUMMY,NEW_DUMMY
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot `cd` into a server. That is just not how the command works. I don't know why it would work in you local shell, maybe you have installed some plugin (which would be feasible in zsh or similar shells).

You could use the `node` block (given that the server is a Jenkins node) combined with the `dir` block to move to the correct directory.

Comment: Use this plugin to execute commands on remote servers, copy files, etc: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-steps/